# Togglz not working: infinite loop on start

Tags: java, git, jsf, togglz

This is the exception I see every time I run my app.

```
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
```

I remove Togglz and all work. I downloaded an example from here

http://www.hascode.com/2013/06/handling-feature-flags-in-a-java-ee-application-using-togglz/

(in footer the owner let the repo git clone https://bitbucket.org/hascode/jee-feature-flags.git)

I run it in JBoss AS 7.1.1

Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: Seems specific to that sample. Why not leave comment at that site or submit issue over at the github repository?

Comment: I did it. Is rare: the example is equals to the usage official page. I don't understand why happens the infinite loop

Comment: I test the project in a server Glassfish 4.1.1 and work! The problem must be Jboss AS 7.1.1 (I work in standalone mode and not work)

Comment: At the moment this question is inappropriate for StackOverflow: It seems to be about using an application you downloaded, not really troubleshooting your code. If you need help with an application you're writing can you provide more specific examples of what's going on? You only provide part of the exception, and none of the source around where the exception is being thrown or what exactly you're expecting to happen.

Comment: I understand. I started a JSF 2.1 project with JBoss AS 7.1 and I added Togglz library to use flag features. When I run in Jboss this begin load until stack overflow, then I see the exception I write in the question a lot of times. The configuration is equals like official Togglz page. I can't fix it yet